# How did Vader survive that long on Mustafar?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, revenge-of-the-sith

I just watched Episode III recently and I was surprised by what seems to be a plot hole regarding Vader and the speed of spaceships.

### The setting

The point in question is when Vader and Kenobi are fighting each other on Mustafar.

As they start fighting, Sidious is on Coruscant and he says something among the lines of "I sense Vader is in danger, let's go help him" and goes.

When we watch the film, it seems rather instinctive that the whole fight is shown on screen, not parts of it.

Then, after a few minutes (on-screen time, not plot-time), Vader is dismembered.

After a few more minutes (on-screen time, not plot-time), Vader is saved by Sidious who just left what seemed to be something like a Theta-class T-2c shuttle (which has a hyperdrive rating of 1).

The base hyperspeed time for Outer Rim to Core planets is 96 hours, according to [this chart](http://www.starwars-chronicles.com/Hyperspace_Travel_Time.htm).

Let's say that you want to go from Tatooine to Alderaan and that you're on a an illegally modified Corellian YT-1300 with a .5 hyperdrive (yep, that one ship), it still takes some time, but let's not reduce it too much and take the arbitrary number of 3 hours since some passengers actually take the time to entertain / train themselves.

It happens that, according to the [galaxy map](http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130325041255/starwars/images/1/10/MainGalaxy.png), the route from Coruscant to Mustafar (using the Hydian Way) is about as long as the route from Tatooine to Alderaan (using the Corellian Run).

### The question

So... did Vader really survive for, at the very least, 3 hours lying on the verges of a volcano? Ok, he's a boss regarding the Force, but still, he just lost 3 limbs, was slightly cooked, had a "dealbreaker" fight with his lover, and there is no indication that he knows that any rescue is coming. The whole film showed that he was rather mentally unstable (not crazy, just unstable). Yet he had the will to control the Force to survive with all that?

Or maybe was the fight really long?

#### Notes:

"Legends"-based answers are acceptable since all the base elements used here were written before the canon-reset.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that Obi-Wan and Anakin weren't lovers. Oh wait, you meant Padmé...

Comment: "The ship travels at the speed of plot".

Comment: @Richard I'm pretty sure Padmé and Anakin weren't either, from what I saw.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard So how did she get pregnant with children known to be Anakin's children, then?

Comment: Also, downvoting because you were surprised about a plot hole in Episodes 1-3. Seriously, that's not surprising.

Comment: The one assumption that is most likely in error is that Sidious and team flew the entire trip in the Theta-class T-2c shuttle, instead of using a larger ship with better engines and just landing in the shuttle.

Comment: The force doesn't need him to control it in order to work, sometimes it just does it's thing.

Comment: Things are implied to be happening simultaneously by the way the sequence is edited.

Comment: I felt that my answer was pretty comprehensive, given the reference to the novelisation. Is there anything else you'd like to see addressed before considering an acceptance?

Comment: Yes: your answer only says "it's only minutes, here's proof". I made clear that, in my view, it wasn't possible for it to be minute. And you swipe all my "settings" section with your answer. I've upvoted your answer but I can't accept it while that is not addressed. Technically, you've answered, but you haven't convinced me... yet. What is wrong in my setting?

Answer (score 28):

According to the film's [official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novel)), Obi-Wan sensed that Palpatine and his men were already on final approach to the planet shortly after the duel ended. Given that Padmé needed emergency medical attention, Obi-Wan decided to leave immediately rather than face the arrival of another enemy and further delay.

That means that only a few minutes passed between the end of the duel and the arrival of medical attention for Anakin/Vader. Even so, Palpatine considers it nothing short of a miracle that he's still alive.

> A flash of metal through the sky, and Obi-Wan felt the darkness closing in around them both. **He knew that ship: the Chancellor’s shuttle. Now, he supposed, the Emperor’s shuttle**. Yoda had failed. He might have died. He might have left Obi-Wan alone: the last Jedi. Below his feet, Darth Vader burst into flame. “I hate you,” he screamed.
>
> Obi-Wan looked down. It would be a mercy to kill him. He was not
> feeling merciful.
>
> He was feeling calm, and clear, and **he knew that to climb down to that
> black beach might cost him more time than he had. Another Sith Lord
> approached.**
>
> In the end, there was only one choice. It was a choice he had made
> many years before, when he had passed his trials of Jedi Knighthood,
> and sworn himself to the Jedi forever. In the end, he was still
> Obi-Wan Kenobi, and he was still a Jedi, and he would not murder a
> helpless man.
>
> He would leave it to the will of the Force. He turned and walked away.
> After a moment, he began to run.

Comment: You add stuff but don't answer the question. Could you please answer it? That means interpret what you have written? From what I read and the comments I wrote in the question itself, you're basically saying "the fight lasted very long". Is that what you're implying?

Comment: Also, you're answering from the point of view of Obi-Wan which doesn't say a thing about Vader. And where is all the time I accounted for?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Huh?  He did answer your question.  No, “only a few minutes passed”.  There's the answer.

Comment: You're making a lot of assumptions about how long it took Palatine to get there. The novel and plan of events show that to be false.

Comment: @Richard If so, wouldn't it be right to explain those false assumptions clearly in the answer?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I think you could be getting caught up on the “I sense Vader is in danger, let's go help him” scene.  It's likely that happened hours prior to the fight, and it's shown just before because editing a movie that way is better storytelling.  Also, because The Force.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson It's possible. That's why I explicitly wrote "screen-time". It might even be an answer in its own right, I believe.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire No, I'm just putting Richard's arriving-a-few-minutes-before together with your distance/time estimations.  There's really no way for both to be true without it being story-presentational.  Richard can disagree with me if he likes, but I think this what he meant— Sidious left much earlier.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson - I'm not disagreeing, I'm just not answering a question that wasn't asked. "How did Vader survive that long on Mustafar?" does not equal "How did Palpatine get to Mustafar so quickly".

Comment: @Richard The title is... a title, not a question. It's an interrogative form, but the actual question has a whole section in the OP, clearly labelled as that, since edit 0. If you check the history, the original title was even different.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire According to you, the question is: "So... did Vader really survive for, at the very least, 3 hours lying on the verges of a volcano?".  Richard answered that, by saying "no, he survived for 5 minutes."