# How long did it take Palpatine to travel from Coruscant to Mustafar?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

Inspired by [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/112954/14710) about how long Anakin survived on Mustafar after his fight with Obi-Wan, the questioner gives (Legends) evidence to suggest it would take a minimum of three hours to get to Mustafar from Coruscant.

In Disney canon, is there a description of when, in relation to the fight on Mustafar, Palpatine left Coruscant, and how long it took him to get to Mustafar?

Comment: @phantom42 - Have a look at the discussion [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/112955/20774)

Comment: After some thought in chat the correct answer was determined to be 14 parsecs.

Comment: @JackBNimble - The answer is, of course, Midi-chlorians.

Comment: @JackBNimble - **12 parsecs**!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's nothing in the film's [Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novel)) to indicate whether the warning the Emperor felt was in realtime (nor anything to specify the passage of time between receiving the warning and his arrival at Mustafar) but given that Mustafar is described as being "*a remote mining colony*" on the "*Outer Rim*" this strongly suggests that the travel time in hyperspace must have been more than the few minutes that the fight went on.

My instinct is that the Emperor was receiving some kind of [Force Premonition](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_vision) about his apprentice being in danger rather than sensing the fight directly:

> *He didn’t have time to direct the search personally. **The Force hummed
>   a warning in his bones: Lord Vader was in danger. Mortal danger.***
>
> *Clones scattered. He stopped one officer. “You. Call the shuttle dock
>   and tell them I’m on my way. Have my ship warmed and ready.”*
>
> *The officer saluted, and Palpatine, with vigor that surprised even
>   himself, ran.*

Nor is there anything in the film's [Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(junior_novelization))

> *Sidious knew he should have been pleased with the outcome of the fight. He had won, though it had been a near thing. **But an uneasiness was growing within him, a sense of some threat not yet resolved.**
>
>   Below, the clone commander boarded a Senate pod and rose to the level of the podium. “There is no sign of his body, sir,” he reported, saluting.
>
>   “Then he is not dead,” Mas Amedda replied.
>
>   **Sidious nodded and reached out with the dark side, trying to sense where his enemy was hiding. As he did, the feeling of risk grew stronger, and he understood. Not a threat to him, but to his apprentice. He must see to this personally.** “Double your search,” he told the clone commander, though he doubted they would find anything. He turned to Mas Amedda. “Tell Captain Kagi to prepare my shuttle for immediate takeoff. I sense Lord Vader is in danger.”
>
>   Mas Amedda bowed. “Yes, my Master.”*

---

Moving down the canon scale, the Legends canon [Tokyopop! Star Wars: Revenge of the Sith Cine-Manga](http://www.rebelscum.com/jedijournals/issue.asp?id=ISU2128) indicates that Anakin's fight with Obi-Wan was going at the same time as Palpatine's fight with Yoda:

[image]

The film's [Graphic Novelisation](https://www.darkhorse.com/Books/10-559/Star-Wars-Episode-III----Revenge-of-the-Sith-TPB) is even more terse on the subject

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nearly instantly (minutes, not hours) because the shuttle departed **while the fight was still going on** and arrived **Just as Obi-Wan was leaving with Padme** right after the fight.

### Arrival

> At the landing deck, C-3PO stood on the skiff's landing
>   ramp, waving frantically. "Master Kenobi! Please hurry!"
>   "Where's Padme?"
>   "Already inside, sir, but she is badly hurt." Obi-Wan ran up the
>   ramp to the skiff's cockpit and fired the engines.
>
> **As the Chancellor's shuttle curved in toward the landing deck, the sleek
>   mirror-finished skiff streaked for the stars. Obi-Wan never looked
>   back**.

### Departure

Please note that he left **during the fight** (which, in the film, only lasted several minutes)

> Clones scattered. He stopped one officer. "You. Call the
>   shuttle dock and tell them I'm on my way. Have my ship warmed
>   and ready."
>   The officer saluted, and Palpatine, with vigor that surprised
>   even himself, ran.

and later, the text shows the fight is **ongoing** after the Emperor is calling for the shuttle:

> With Anakin's grip on his wrists bending his arms near to
>   breaking, forcing both their lightsabers down in a slow but unstoppable arc, Obi-Wan let go. Of everything. (all quotes from Chapter 20 of Stover's Episode III novelization)

### After-Fight time till arrival

And we know that Obi-Wan **ran** from the fight to the skiff, and based on the film it wasn't a large distance since it took them only a few minutes **of intense fight** to cover it before:

> He would leave it to the will of the Force. He turned and
>   walked away. After a moment, he began to run.
>   **He began to run because he realized, if he was fast enough,
>   there was one thing he still could do for Anakin**. He still could do
>   honor to the memory of the man he had loved, and to the vanished Order they both had served.
>   At the landing deck, C-3PO stood on the skiff's landing
>   ramp, waving frantically. "Master Kenobi! Please hurry!"
>   "Where's Padme?"
>   "Already inside, sir, but she is badly hurt." Obi-Wan ran up the
>   ramp to the skiff's cockpit and fired the engine

Comment: The question was how long it took between Palpatine winning his fight with Yoda and his arrival at Mustafar.

Comment: @Richard - updated.